# Get bound object based on it's id

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this `textbox` for clients to search for `id`:

```
Enter Id: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="temp.id"> 
<button (click)="myEvent()">My Button</button>

<table class='table' *ngIf="collection">
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of collection">
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In the `myEvent` method, I don't know how should I get the relevant bound object of given Id, so that I get it's `name` property and send it to my WEB API:

```
temp: any = { id: '' };

myEvent() {
    this.http.get('url', {
        params: {
            id: this.temp.id,
            name: ???
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Is <button (click)="myEvent()">My Button</button> inside your *ngFor loop?

Comment: @RukshanDangalla No. It's outside of the table as I've shown in my updated question.

Comment: @RukshanDangalla If the solution is to place my button inside *ngFor loop, I will change my code. Just please show me how should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your collection of items, you can find the one by the `id` property a few ways.

Here is one way using the [array `find` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
myEvent() {
    const item = this.collection.find(i => i.id === this.temp.id);

    if (!item) {
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the const type? Why shouldn't it be of type my interface?

Comment: `const` is a keyword like `var` and `let`. It just signifies that this variable should not be written to again. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: And then how should I get the name from const item? Since my intellisence is not working after it! this is not working `name:item.name,`

Comment: The collection is an array of my interface, that I have `id` and `name` inside my interface.

Comment: Your `item` should be inferred to be `YourInterfaceType | undefined`. Is it complaining because you may be getting a property of an `undefined` object or is it something else?

Comment: The `undefined` part is because if `find (...)` can't find a match it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Is your `id` property a `number` or a `string`on your objects in the collection?

Comment: Yes it inferred to be MyInterfaceType | undefined. But I don't know what should I do?

Comment: Isn't this line my problem? `temp: any = { id: '' };`

Comment: No, that's fine. Is the `id` on `MyInterfaceType` a `string`?

Comment: Yes. It is string!

Comment: If you add in a check to make sure the item was found, you should get rid of any issues. See update above.

Comment: I am really confused. It appeared after I run my project once!!! can you please explain why???

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What appeared?

Comment: Now I can access the item's properties after I have run my project once. Before that I couldn't access to it's properties as I said already.

Comment: If you added that check in, it was letting the typescript compiler know that any code that gets past it will have an `item` that is not `undefined`, which would allow you to then safely access the properties. So instead of the `item` being seen as type `MyInterfaceType | undefined` it sees it as just `MyInterfaceType` (after that `if` block of code)

Comment: Thanks for your complete explanation. Can you please tell me, can I send the whole item to my WEB API as parameter? How should I pass a parameter of type `MyInterface` and get in server as equivalent model??

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript's native method find() to get the exact object and access name field in component.ts

```
let name = this.collection.find(t=> t.id == this.temp.id).name;
```

Then you should be able to pass the name with your I'd to the API.

Comment: Thanks. It is fine for `let name = this.collection.find(t=> t.id == this.temp.id)` but when I type name it doesn't show anything.

Comment: I can't access the object's properties after find method!

Comment: You should be able to use name ,just add a console.log(name) and see

Comment: Thanks.  Can you please tell me, can I send the whole item (`let item = this.collection.find(t=> t.id == this.temp.id)`) to my WEB API as parameter? How should I pass a parameter of type `MyInterface` and get in server as equivalent model??

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Enter Id: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="temp.id"> 

<table class='table' *ngIf="collection">
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let item of collection">
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td><button (click)="myEvent(item)">My Button</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And get the selected item in your *myEvent*

```
myEvent(item: any) {
  this.http.get('url', {
      params: {
          id: item.id,
          name: item.name
    }
 })
}
```